# Install PHP both as CGI and CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cgi, slackware

I'm trying to set up development environment for some old projects in PHP 5.1.4. It needs to run as CGI (or fastcgi) under apache and I would like to have cli binary. My configure options are:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr/local/php-dev \
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-dev/etc \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-dbase \
--enable-exif \
--enable-fastcgi \
--enable-force-cgi-redirect \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-memory-limit \
--enable-soap \
--enable-track-vars \
--enable-trans-sid \
--enable-versioning \
--enable-xslt \
--with-curl=/usr/local/php-libs/curl-7.12.2 \
--with-freetype \
--with-freetype-dir \
--with-gd \
--with-iconv \
--with-jpeg-dir \
--with-mhash \
--with-mime-magic \
--with-mssql=/usr/local/php-libs/freetds-0.64 \
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql5 \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql5 \
--with-pear \
--with-ttf \
--with-xslt-sablot=/usr/local/sablot-1.0.3 \
--with-zlib
```

After installing it, I have only these files in `/usr/local/php-dev/bin`:

```
pear
peardev
pecl
php
php-config
phpize
```

I would expect also `php-cgi` or `php-cli`. When running `./php -v` from command line it shows:

```
PHP 5.1.4 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Sep 23 2010 09:46:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
 with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
```

So I only have CGI version and when I try to run CLI specific scripts, variables `$argv` and `$argc` are `NULL`.

Is there a way to have both CLI and CGI versions? (system: slackware 13.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php:

> The name, location and existence of the CLI/CGI binaries will differ depending on how PHP is installed on your system. By default when executing make, both the CGI and CLI are built and placed as sapi/cgi/php-cgi and sapi/cli/php respectively, in your PHP source directory. You will note that both are named php. What happens during make install depends on your configure line. If a module SAPI is chosen during configure, such as apxs, or the --disable-cgi option is used, the CLI is copied to {PREFIX}/bin/php during make install otherwise the CGI is placed there. So, for example, if --with--apxs is in your configure line then the CLI is copied to {PREFIX}/bin/php during make install. If you want to override the installation of the CGI binary, use make install-cli after make install. Alternatively you can specify --disable-cgi in your configure line.

So, did you try `make install-cli`? Do you have a `sapi` dir with those two?

Comment: Thanks, it was in sapi folder. This documentation fragment should be moved to http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php

Comment: You can add a documentation bug report at http://bugs.php.net. Although real bug fixes might take a while. from personal experience a reasonable documentation fix takes only couple of days to roll out.